# how to achieve custom progressbar in angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, progress-bar, angular-material-7

I am trying to achieve following determinate progress bar with percentage inside and the fraction at the top of the progress percentage in angular.

[progress bar i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBkHc.png)

I saw material progress bar but not sure how can I achieve like the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best solution, but you can use `<span>` and `[ngStyle]` to display both the fraction and the progress percentage and control their positions with the `CSS` styling. Something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ltyru-zjztfs?file=app%2Fprogress-bar-determinate-example.html)